# how to add filter to EF by Dependency Injection

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection

I want to add some conditions(where) to linq in ef codefirst.

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
            var u= context.Users;
            **u.where(my where condition)**
        }
```

Is there some way to let me di into all selects ,
eg:BeforeSelected?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a wrapper over DbContext.

```
public class EfWrapper:Context
{
 private DbContext _dbContext;

  public EfWrapper(DbContext context){
    _dbContext=context;
  }

  public IEnumerable <User> Users{
     get
     {
        return _dbContext.Users.Where(my where condition);
     }
 }


}
```